# div will not change color when mouse enters the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background, mouseenter

I'm having trouble changing the background color of a div when the mouse enters the field of the div.  I'm using javascript/jquery to attempt this but nothing seems to be happening.   Posted is a link of the html I'm trying to access, the css, and the javascript.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working???  I can't seem to figure it out and the other examples on here have 1000's of solutions that just do not work when I try to use them.

// THE HTML

```
    <section class="box content">
     <div id="projects"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Title Three</h2>
      <p>content goes here</p>
      <div class="someContent">

        <p>more stuff change me
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

// THE CSS

```
.someContent {
width: 60%;
margin-left: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
text-align: left;
}

.hightLight {
background-color: yellow;
border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

// THE JAVASCRIPT

```
(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").on("mouseenter", function() {
$(this).addClass("highLight");
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
$(this).removeClass("highLight");
});
});
```

// lastly the tags added at my html top

```
<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- js -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
```

Why isn't the div ".someContent" not changing ? >-<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your `.hightLight` selector in your CSS to `.highLight`. 
And also add a `$` in front of your first line of JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: Both answers seem helpful to the question so I will vote up on both.

Answer (score 3):

Though I'm a big fan of javascript, this is a use css case:

```
.someContent :hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks of the speeding reply!  I've figured it out in css with the hover, but I wanted to use javascript for this because I eventually want to add an animation where the div extends left and down slightly when the user mouses into the field and animates back to normal when they leave it.  If I can figure out how to change the div elements in javascript I should be able to extend the width and top with animate transition: yadda yadda

Comment: @user3586343 these days you can easily do these kind of animations in CSS too.